# xslt with html table sort specific td

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm new at XSLT language so i don't now how to do that..i want to sort all rows by category from table except the count products..i don't want to affect the order off count_products..please help..the code i have made so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
     <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/xsl_style.css" type="text/css"/>
     </head>
    <body>
    <div class="tableStyle" >
    <table>
      <tr bgcolor="#B5E4EA">
        <td>A/A</td>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Corpration</td>
        <td>Category</td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="auction_products/product">
      <xsl:sort select="category"/> 
        <tr>
          <td><a href="live_auctions.php"><xsl:value-of select="count_products"/></a></td>
          <td><a href="live_auctions.php"><xsl:value-of select="product_name"/></a></td>
          <td><a href="live_auctions.php"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></a></td>
          <td><a href="live_auctions.php"><xsl:value-of select="corporation"/></a></td>
          <td><a href="live_auctions.php"><xsl:value-of select="category"/></a></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This question doesn't make sense - you're sorting the _rows_, not the columns.

Comment: sorry..you are correct. i want to sort the rows by category without to affect the count_products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the rows to be sorted but the `count_products` column to come out in document order then you'd need a trick like this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="allProducts" select="auction_products/product" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$allProducts">
  <xsl:sort select="category"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
    <tr>
      <td><a href="live_auctions.php"><xsl:value-of select="$allProducts[$pos]/count_products"/></a></td>
      <td><a href="live_auctions.php"><xsl:value-of select="product_name"/></a></td>
      <td><a href="live_auctions.php"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></a></td>
      <td><a href="live_auctions.php"><xsl:value-of select="corporation"/></a></td>
      <td><a href="live_auctions.php"><xsl:value-of select="category"/></a></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

to take the `count_products` child from the nth product regardless of the sorting applied to the for-each.

Of course, if `count_products` is really just a counter (1, 2, 3, ...) then you could just use `<xsl:value-of select="$pos" />` directly.